# Why this lisp recursive macro doesn't work?

Tags: macros, lambda, lisp, scheme, guile

I have macro let-- (like let* using lambdas) in guile:

```
(define (let-make-lambdas pairs body)
    (if (null? pairs)
        `((lambda () ,@body))
        `((lambda (,(caar pairs))
            ,(let-make-lambdas (cdr pairs) body))
          ,(cadar pairs))))

(define-macro (let-- pairs . body)
    (let-make-lambdas pairs body))
```

it works fine when I use an external function to do code generation, but the code below (with is just a macro) doesn't work:

```
(define-macro (let-- pairs . body)
    (if (null? pairs)
        `((lambda () ,@body))
        `((lambda (,(caar pairs))
            ,(let-- (cdr pairs) body))
          ,(cadar pairs))))
```

why?

Comment: Forgot a parenthesis? :P

Comment: The macro call does not seem to correspond to its definition: the dot is missing.

Comment: @sds The `.` is used for defining what would be `&rest` lists in Common Lisp.  In the first case, jcubic is defining a functional to perform the code expansion, and the _macro_ _does_ include the `.`

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: what I meant was that the invocation of the macro must either have a `.` (as in my answer) or a `@` (as in yours)

Comment: @sds Oh, I see what you mean.  The `(let-- ...)` _within_ the definition could have been `(let-- (cdr pairs) . body)`.  Right (as long as the other issue was resolved).  Sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second, you don't want

```
,(let-- (cdr pairs) body)
```

but rather

```
(let-- ,(cdr pairs) ,@body)
```

That is, your direct macro implementation should be

```
(define-macro (let-- pairs . body)
    (if (null? pairs)
        `((lambda () ,@body))
        `((lambda (,(caar pairs))
            (let-- ,(cdr pairs) ,@body))
          ,(cadar pairs))))
```

You don't want to evaluate the inner `(let-- ...)` at macro expansion time;  it's part of the source that should be generated.  (Of course, it will be macroxpanded very shortly after.)  To highlight this, consider a macro that turns

```
(plus a b c d)
```

into

```
(+ a (+ b (+ c d)))
```

It would need to expand like

```
(+ ,(car args) (plus ,@(cdr args)))
```

but not

```
(+ ,(car args) ,(plus (cdr args)))
```

because the latter will try to evaluate `(plus '(b c d))`, which won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think Joshua nailed the answer to you problem. I just want to point out that `Scheme` standard use `syntax-rules` and `syntax-case`. It could be something like like this with `syntax-rules`:

```
;; make let* with lambdas
(define-syntax let--
  (syntax-rules ()
    ;; base case, last pair
    ((let-- ((key1 value1)) . body) 
     ((lambda (key1) . body ) value1))

    ;; default case, several
    ((let-- ((key1 value1) . kv-pairs) . body) 
     ((lambda (key1) (let-- kv-pairs . body)) value1))))

(let-- ((a 'a) (b a) (c b)) (list a b c)) ; ==> (a a a)
```

Comment: I prefer lisp-macros and scheme implementations that support them, but nevertheless thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working Common Lisp version:

```
(defmacro let1-- (pairs . body)
  (if (null pairs)
      `((lambda () ,@body))
      `((lambda (,(caar pairs))
         (let-- ,(cdr pairs) . ,body))
         ,(cadar pairs))))
> (macroexpand '(let1-- ((a 1) (b 2)) (+ b a)))
((LAMBDA (A) (LET-- ((B 2)) (+ B A))) 1) ;
T
> (let1-- ((a 1) (b 2)) (+ b a))
3
```

The corresponding Scheme version is, I guess,

```
(define-macro (let-- pairs . body)
    (if (null? pairs)
        `((lambda () ,@body))
        `((lambda (,(caar pairs))
            (let-- ,(cdr pairs) . ,body))
          ,(cadar pairs))))
```